# Comparing custom iterators

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare a custom iterator in a loop.

```
for(auto i = list.begin(); !(i == list.end()); ++i) {

}
```

This code yield the following error.

```
Invalid operands to binary expression 
('List<double>::iterator' and 'List<double>::iterator')
```

But I indeed implemented the comparison operator.

```
class iterator: public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, value_type> {
    const element *current;
public:
    const bool operator==( iterator &rhs) const {
            return current == rhs.current;
    }
```

Why is this failing?

Comment: Try `const bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) const` maybe.

Comment: Add this as an answer please. You're correct.

Comment: `boost::iterator_facade` and `boost::iterator_adaptor` make this sort of thing much easier to get right and complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-constant lvalue reference cannot bind to temporary values (such as `list.end()`). Fortunately, you don't need to mutate the iterators in the comparator and can thus pass them by *constant* reference:

```
const bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) const
{
    return current == rhs.current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning a `const bool` 
change your operator overloading as

```
const bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) const{
            return current == rhs.current;
    }
```